# Rails Redis Reset Counters to 0

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, redis, counter

I would like to reset the value of a REDIS counter to 0 in a Rails 4 app.

I use hincrby to increment counters

```
 $redis.hincrby("user:likes", "key", 1)
```

I can't delete the key with hdel http://redis.io/commands/hdel because I need to get the key often.

GETSET is atomic and could do the job http://redis.io/commands/getset, as in the example

```
 GETSET mycounter "0"
```

But since I use hashes I need to use HSET http://redis.io/commands/hset

```
$redis.hset("user:likes", "key", "0")
```

It's not specified if hset is atomic, anyone used hset to reset redis counters to 0? If it's not a good option to reset a counter to 0, any idea how to do it?

Comment: Not sure I understand. If you need to set it to zero, set it to zero. Or are you saying you really need GETSET functionality, but for the hash?

Comment: It's specified in the docs that GETSET is atomic but it's not specified for HSET, so is HSET atomic?

Comment: I don't know, but GETSET is two operations. HSET is one, so I imagine would be atomic, no?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is atomic, so if you run `$redis.hset("user:likes", "key", "0")`, it doesn't affect other fields inside the "user:likes" hash besides the field: "key"

Comment: Don't forget to mark this as answer if this solves your question =)